# Why do we call adjoint Lie groups "adjoint"?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, lie-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

I have recently encountered the definition of an adjoint Lie group, i.e. a Lie group which is semisimple with trivial center. My question is, as you might guess from the title :-), why do we call such a group "adjoint"? In other instances where we use the adjective "adjoint", there exists a partner (think left/right adjoint functor) or it comes from another mathematical object (think adjoint representation "adjoined" to a Lie group).

Is there a comparable associated object to an adjoint Lie group, or how did this name come to be?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I assume the usage is like for algebraic groups, i.e. the one sitting on the opposite end from the simply connected one.

Comment: Any such usage has to come from the adjoint action of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ via $\mathrm{ad}_x(y) = [x,y]$. Now adjoint operators usually satisfy something like $(Ax,y) = (x,Ay)$,  and I guess $\mathrm{ad}_x(y) = [x,y]=-[y,x]=-\mathrm{ad}_y(x)$? I'm curious who first use adjoint action/representation in this sense, it might go back quite far (certainly before left/right adjoints!)

Comment: @DietrichBurde, in the automorphic forms business, there is terminology "(semi-simple?) group of adjoint type", which _operationally_ means that it's the image of the Adjoint action of a semi-simple Lie group on its Lie algebra.

Comment: I have heard this, too. But I cannot find the term "adjoint Lie group" in google. It does not exists, it seems. What definition exactly is meant?

Comment: I've found this definition in Milne's Notes on Shimura Varieties on Page 6, https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/svi.pdf

Comment: Fyi, I assume it’s called that because the adjoint representation Ad of G is faithful. So in other words, G=Ad(something), and hence is an adjoint group. The def was probably invented by people mostly interested in semisimple groups, so I think the “adjoint” part refers more to the centerlessness than the semisimplicity.

Comment: As for why the adjoint rep is called that, idk, maybe it’s just the colloquial meaning of adjoint as “the natural associated object”. Or maybe someone can think of some more mathy connection.